# is it possible to use case statement + round() in database

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

i have table called 'test' and want to calculate based on different codes, most of them should be saved in 5 decimals except certain code, like containing jpy in 3 decimals, and xua in 2 decimals

```
create table test(
      id int, ymd date,
      code varchar(10),
      price int
    )

insert into test(id, ymd, code, price) values
   (1, '2019-01-01', 'auus', 75125),
   (2, '2019-01-02', 'nzus', 68541),
   (3, '2019-01-03', 'xuaus', 131485),
   (4, '2019-01-04', 'aujp', 77852),
   (5, '2019-01-05', 'usjp', 110852),
   (6, '2019-01-06', 'xuaus', 131091)
```

So my execute code is:

```
select id, ymd, code, price, 
 case
when code like '%xua%' then round(price/100,2)
when code like '%jp%' then round(price/1000,3)
else round(price/100000,5)
end as t
from test
```

ideal result:

```
 id     ymd     code    price   t
 1  2019-01-01  auus    75125   0.75125
 2  2019-01-02  nzus    68541   0.68541
 3  2019-01-03  xuaus   131485  1314.85
 4  2019-01-04  aujp    77852   77.852
 5  2019-01-05  usjp    110852  110.852
 6  2019-01-06  xuaus   131091  1310.91
```

intersting, above sql works well with Mysql, but i am using mariadb, and just can't get results as same as mysql, spent 2 days to fix problem, but still don't know, please help

Comment: How many decimal places do you want for 'xuajp' or 'jpxua'?

Comment: @RickJames,  5 decimals for all, except any codes having'xua' for 2 decimals, and 'jp' for 3

Comment: Thanks, @RickJames, i got same solution as you did, but i don't know why round() is not working case in mariadb, but works fine with mysql, also if i use format, then all numbers will be chagnged into string format? does it matter, i tried to use numbers (from above t colomn) then do anther calculation, then all decimals all over the place plus incorrect result

Comment: What do you mean "not working".  "Rounding" is a matter of changing the _value_.  MariaDB "rounds" correctly, but does not "display" the way you expected.  "FORMAT" does both "rounding" and changing the "display".

Comment: sorry @RickJames, i am a beginner, i though by using round(), it will remain the value as numbers, however, if changing into format, the values will be changed into a string?

Comment: In _most_ contexts (withing MySQL), a string containing a numeric value can be used as a number.  For example: `SELECT ROUND(1.78, 0) + ROUND(5.67);` yields numeric `8`.  Similarly, numbers can turn into strings when needed:  `SELECT CONCAT(2.22, 66.78);` --> the string `"2.2266.78"`.

Comment: A clue (when using the mysql commandline tool, which I am doing):  Numbers are displayed right-justified; strings are displayed left-justfified.  This can be seen in `code`, `price` and `t` in the two examples in my Answer.

Comment: i see @RickJames, thanks , so is it same for maria db?

Comment: Just now, I added MySQL 5.6 results to my Answer.

Comment: i see the difference from the t column,  not noticeable, but it does slightly differently from what you have mentioned, thanks @RickJames, also would like to have output as discussed earlier, then do further calculation baesed on it, however, error appears, not sure why ?

Comment: In the `o-0.1` case, I do not know whether `DOUBLE` crept in with the value of `o`, or with the subtract.

Comment: It may be best to create a real column for `t`, of type `DECIMAL(14,5)` (or similar).

Comment: This is a tough problem, for which there is no "right" answer.  Think of exactly splitting an inheritance of $1000 among 3 heirs.

Comment: thanks, i see @RickJames, actually someone told me that all numbers related db, should be set up as int in the table structure, then do multiple or divide to relfect real data, that's why i change all decimals into int, then change int back to decimal etc. Actually above db would be used for recoridng currency, so most of currency would be in 5 decimals, but some can be in 2 or 3 decimals, so what do you think the best idea for my purpose, perhaps i need to redesign whole structure again

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select id, ymd, code, price, 
    ->  case
    -> when code like '%xua%' then round(price/100,2)
    -> when code like '%jp%' then round(price/1000,3)
    -> else round(price/100000,5)
    -> end as t
    -> from test  ;
+------+------------+-------+--------+------------+
| id   | ymd        | code  | price  | t          |
+------+------------+-------+--------+------------+
|    1 | 2019-01-01 | auus  |  75125 |    0.75125 |
|    2 | 2019-01-02 | nzus  |  68541 |    0.68541 |
|    3 | 2019-01-03 | xuaus | 131485 | 1314.85000 |
|    4 | 2019-01-04 | aujp  |  77852 |   77.85200 |
|    5 | 2019-01-05 | usjp  | 110852 |  110.85200 |
|    6 | 2019-01-06 | xuaus | 131091 | 1310.91000 |
+------+------------+-------+--------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Using `FORMAT` instead of `ROUND`:

```
mysql> select id, ymd, code, price,
         case when code like '%xua%' then format(price/100,2)
              when code like '%jp%' then format(price/1000,3)
              else format(price/100000,5) end as t from test;
+------+------------+-------+--------+----------+
| id   | ymd        | code  | price  | t        |
+------+------------+-------+--------+----------+
|    1 | 2019-01-01 | auus  |  75125 | 0.75125  |
|    2 | 2019-01-02 | nzus  |  68541 | 0.68541  |
|    3 | 2019-01-03 | xuaus | 131485 | 1,314.85 |
|    4 | 2019-01-04 | aujp  |  77852 | 77.852   |
|    5 | 2019-01-05 | usjp  | 110852 | 110.852  |
|    6 | 2019-01-06 | xuaus | 131091 | 1,310.91 |
+------+------------+-------+--------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@version;
+----------------------------------------+
| @@version                              |
+----------------------------------------+
| 10.3.11-MariaDB-1:10.3.11+maria~bionic |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that it includes a "thousands-separator" when appropriate.  See the 3rd argument to `FORMAT()` or the Locale setting to change that.

I suspect it is the *display* process that is formatting the output differently.  By switching from `ROUND` to `FORMAT`, I managed to get MariaDB's output to be nearly the same as MySQL's.  The remaining difference is the added commas ("thousands separators"), which may show as '.' for some Locales.

In contrast, for MySQL 5.6.22:

```
+------+------------+-------+--------+---------+
| id   | ymd        | code  | price  | t       |
+------+------------+-------+--------+---------+
|    1 | 2019-01-01 | auus  |  75125 | 0.75125 |
|    2 | 2019-01-02 | nzus  |  68541 | 0.68541 |
|    3 | 2019-01-03 | xuaus | 131485 | 1314.85 |
|    4 | 2019-01-04 | aujp  |  77852 |  77.852 |
|    5 | 2019-01-05 | usjp  | 110852 | 110.852 |
|    6 | 2019-01-06 | xuaus | 131091 | 1310.91 |
+------+------------+-------+--------+---------+
```

The *numeric values* are the same, but the *display* is different.  The difference *seems* to come from the commandline tool `mysql`, not from `ROUND`, itself.  Note that `t` is right-justified, implying that the values are seen as numeric.

If this offends someone enough, file a bug report with MariaDB.

`77.75200000000001` -- This is representative of some intermediate computation using `DOUBLE` instead of all `DECIMAL`.  MySQL (and MariaDB) do a reasonably good job of second-guessing where the number are headed.  And *usually* they get away with whatever is done.

In `DOUBLE`, `77.75200000000001` is not *exactly* equal to the `DECIMAL` `77.752` because one is binary, one is decimal.  For this reason, I often recommend *not* using `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` for "money".

Assuming your real goal is to represent a monetary value as `77.7520000000000000000000000...`, that is exactly '77.752', and, assuming you need at most 5 decimal places for the various values, I recommend you do this:

```
t DECIMAL(m, 5)
```

where `m` is a suitably large number for any values you may eventually have.  For the numbers given, `(9,5)` will suffice, but I suspect you should do more like `DECIMAL(14,5)` to allow for a billion dollars/euros/yen/etc.

What I don't know is where in the processing `DOUBLE` crept in.

**Latest 'advice'**

- Use `DECIMAL(14,5)` for all monetary values in your system, not `INT`.
- `14,5` lets you get up to a billion 'dollars'; change that as needed for your expected max value.
- Ignore my comments about `FORMAT()`; it seems to be too confusing.
- Get rid of the `CASE` clause, at least for that particular usage.
- Most arithmetic among `DECIMAL` values will be exact, and not encounter `77.75200000000001`.  If it crops up again, start a new Question and include all the steps, datatypes, etc, involved in the computation.
- The above notes refer to storing and computing.  For *displaying*, please specify the requirements:

Plan A: 5 decimal places is OK.
Plan B: need to round to 3 or 2 decimals for some values.
Plan C: You have application code, not in SQL, that can deal with the issue.
Plan D:...

Comment: ???? sorry, 'Note that it includes a "thousands-separator" when appropriate. See the 3rd argument to FORMAT() or the Locale setting to change that.' -> don't understand, do you think you can explain in more details, @Rick James, thanks

Comment: @coast666 - I added a paragraph.  Meanwhile, please tell us what you want the output to look like.

Comment: thanks for explanations @ Rick James, the output you have displayed is what i want, however, after changing the format, if i want to  do further calculation based on above output, then some calculations will be incorrect, e.g https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=fa7cbecff607ec63d1d0f309856a8d4f.  , see id 3, 4, 6 ... can you see what i mean ....

Comment: @ Rick James, would like to have above output as base, then do further calculation based on it

Comment: _Calculations_ should be the same.  That is 1310.91000 and 1310.91 represent the _same number_, so any calculations should come out the same.  Well, I see 77.75200000000001...

Comment: i am not sure if you see the link i have provided @ Rick James, see id 3, 4, 6 (o-0.1 column), that's incorrect

Comment: `0.9` comes from the thousands-separator confusing the issue.  If you really want numeric results, then avoid `FORMAT`.  When converting a string (eg, `1,310.91`) to a number, the parsing stops at the first character that is non numeric (`,`), so that is treated as `1`.  `o-0.1` = `1-0.1` = `0.9`.

Comment: sounds very confusing @Rick James, how can i convert string into number then? is it mean i need to use locale (change ',' into '.' ) so that database can treat them as numbers ? i am lost

Comment: Yet another try.  See my "latest advice".

Comment: thanks so much, i will try later on, really appreciated your help indeed!